# Animation of a browser loading page elements?

Tags: html, css

Some time ago, I recall finding a visual explanation of the order web browsers load specific page elements, and how they stack and fit together. I was recently getting back into some web development and tried to find this again, but to no avail.

Anyone have a clue where I might find this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which browser you are using it's a out-of-the-box-tool.

In Chrome just press F12 and the Developener Tools will open up. In the Timeline you'll se the browsers order on loading the pages elements and so on.

In Firefox it's the F12-key too